Relationship in querydsl model is set to null during initialization
I'm working with querydsl for my first time and i run into a problem that i could not explain or figure out why it happens.
I have these 4 entities:
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter

@Entity
public class Rating {

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private Double rate;

    @NotNull
    private Date date;

    @Column(length = 500)
    private String feedback;
    
    @Lob
    @Column(length = 5_000_000)
    private byte[] attachement;

    @OneToOne
    private Civil evaluater;
    
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Professional evaluatee;

    @ManyToOne
    private Indicator indicator;
}

@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("professional")
public class Professional extends Actor {

    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    
    @NotBlank
    private String phone;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private BusinessGroup ownedGroup;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private BusinessGroup businessGroup;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "evaluatee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Rating> ratings;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private SubSector subSector;

    public void addRating(Rating rating) {
        rating.setEvaluatee(this);
        ratings.add(rating);
    }

    public void setRating(List<Rating> ratings) {
        if(Objects.isNull(ratings))
            return;
        this.ratings.clear();
        ratings.forEach(this::addRating);
    }
}

@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter

@Entity
public class SubSector {

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @Id
    private String name;
    
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Sector sector;
}

@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter

@Entity
public class Sector {
    
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @Id
    private String name;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "sector")
    private List<SubSector> subSectors;
}

I'm using querydsl to construct a rest api for searching through Ratings using various parameters, querydsl generates for each of the previous classes QClasses, and i have a controller which takes these parameters and try and construct a JPAQuery:
@Service
public class QslRatingFetcher {

    public static final String RATING_DATE = "date";
    public static final String INDICATOR = "indicator";
    public static final String PERFORMANCE = "performance";
    public static final String PROFESSIONAL = "professional";
    public static final String SECTOR = "sector";
    public static final String SUB_SECTOR = "subsector";
    public static final String GOVERNORATE = "governorate";
    public static final String DELEGATION = "delegation";

    private static final SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER_1;
    private static final SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER_2;
    private static final QRating rating = QRating.rating;
    private static final Map<String, SimpleExpression<?>> bindings;

    static {
        FORMATTER_1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        FORMATTER_2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        bindings = Map.of(RATING_DATE, rating.date, // Date
                INDICATOR, rating.indicator.name, // String
                PERFORMANCE, rating.indicator.performance, // Enum
                PROFESSIONAL, rating.evaluatee.identifier, // String
                SECTOR, rating.evaluatee.subSector.sector.name, // String
                SUB_SECTOR, rating.evaluatee.subSector.name, // String
                GOVERNORATE, rating.evaluatee.address.governorate.name, // String
                DELEGATION, rating.evaluatee.address.delegation.name // String
        );
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    
    private static Map<String, String> purgeCriterions(Map<String, String> criterions) {
        Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator = criterions.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, String> entry = iterator.next();
            if (Objects.isNull(entry.getKey()) || entry.getKey().isBlank() || Objects.isNull(entry.getValue())
                    || entry.getValue().isBlank()) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
        return criterions;
    }

    
    private static Date convertToDate(String value) throws ParseException {
        try {
            return FORMATTER_1.parse(value);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return FORMATTER_2.parse(value);
        }
    }

    
    private static Entry<String, Object> parseValue(String field, String value) {
        try {
            switch (field) {
            case RATING_DATE:
                return Map.entry(field, convertToDate(value));
            case PERFORMANCE:
                return Map.entry(field, Performance.valueOf(value.toUpperCase()));
            default:
                return Map.entry(field, value);
            }
        } catch (ParseException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            String type = e instanceof ParseException ? Date.class.getTypeName() : Performance.class.getTypeName();
            throw ValueConversionException.build(value, type);
        }
    }

    
    private static Map<String, Object> parseCriterions(Map<String, String> criterions) {
        criterions = purgeCriterions(criterions);
        int i = 0;
        Entry<String, Object>[] parsedCriterions = 
                (Entry<String, Object>[]) new Entry[criterions.size()];
        for(Entry<String, String> entry: criterions.entrySet()) {
            parsedCriterions[i++] = parseValue(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        return Map.ofEntries(parsedCriterions);
    }

    
    public List<Rating> fetch(Map<String, String> criterions) {
        
        Map<String, Object> parsedCriterions = parseCriterions(criterions);
        
        BooleanExpression exp = null;
        
        for(Entry<String, Object> entry: parsedCriterions.entrySet()) {
            SimpleExpression ex = bindings.get(entry.getKey());
            if(Objects.isNull(ex)) {
                String msg = MessageFormat.format(Constants.FIELD_NOT_RECOGNIZED, entry.getKey());
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
            } 
            exp = ex.eq(entry.getValue()).and(exp);
        }
        
        JPAQueryFactory queryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(JPQLTemplates.DEFAULT, em);
        return queryFactory.select(rating)
            .where(exp)
            .fetch();
    }
}

The problem lies in the QslRatingFetcher in the static block specifically during the initialization of the bindings Map where the following variable rating.evaluatee.subSector.sector is evaluated to null which causes a NullPointerException during startup:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "name" because "com.backend.dsl.query.QslRatingFetcher.rating.evaluatee.subSector.sector" is null
at com.backend.dsl.query.QslRatingFetcher.(QslRatingFetcher.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
... 44 common frames omitted

I'm using querydsl version 5.0.0 along with spring-boot 2.7.15-SNAPSHOT and java 11,
Is there anything i'm missing?
Thank you

Looking quickly at the code and not validating myself, but it looks like the problem lies because you are using QueryDSL with relationships. As mentioned in the QueryDSL reference documentation in chapter 3.3.1 Path Initialization, it only initializes the first two levels by default. You will need to include @QueryInit to initialize those levels.
So in your example you should just change it to something like this and it should work.
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @QueryInit("*")
    private Professional evaluatee;

